# The exact origin of шёл

Tags: этимология, история-языка, супплетивизм

I'm aware of **шёл**'s derivation from Proto-Slavic `*xьdlъ`, related to **ходить**, but that form still seems irregular — given that **вёл**, which has the exact same relation to **водить**, had `e` rather than `ь` in the root, as demonstrated by the lack of elision in the feminine, neuter, and plural.

My guess is that **шёл**, **шла**, etc. were in fact a contamination of `*хedl-` and the lost regular past participle form of **идти**, which I expect to be `*jьdl-`. Am I correct? And, out of curiosity, what would the hypothetical regular (in Proto-Slavic terms) past tense of **идти** have been in modern Russian? Probably **ёл*, but what of the other forms? **Ила*, **ило* or maybe even **ла*, **ло*?

Comment: произведение из "ход[ить]" в "шёл" совершенно стандартно для русского языка. со всеми сопутсвтующими изменениями - преобразование "х" в "ш" (пример: плохо/оплошать), смена "о" на "ё" (явление тоже достаточно типичное), прибавление суффикса "л" и упрощение трудно произносимых звуковых комбинаций. на выходе имеем слово "шёл".

Comment: @user3694243 «смена "о" на "ё"», по-вашему, «достаточно типичное явление»? а примеры можете привести? (причем не связанные с орфографией, а именно чтобы согласный перед "о" взял да и вдруг палатализировался)

Comment: о каком именно согласном идет речь? согласных поддвергшихся либо поддвергающихся так называемой пал-зации и сопутствующих корней можно по пальцам на руках сосчитать. в дополнение ко всему букву "ш" я всего лишь вариантом букв "х" и "т" считаю, таким же как и букву "ж" получающуюся из "д" или "г". не вижу предмета разяснений. а рассказы о том что нормы использования русского языка из книг происходят, а не из частной практики общения я не способен воспринимать чисто физически. это говоря об орфографических словарях. так что мы видимо на разные темы говорим.

Comment: зачем вам вообще русский, переходите на эсперанто. и извращайтесь там на темы правил орфографии сколько вашему типу людей будет угодно.

Comment: @user3694243 да, похоже, мы говорим на разные темы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не претендуя на ответ... Нашла вот это.

"ход" - "шед" Произошло замещение буквы "Х" на "Ш" в одной из форм изначального глагола "хъдьти" ("ъ" и "ь" - это звук "э" разной краткости, сегодня стал где "о", где "е", где "и", а где и вовсе выпал)

первоначальная форма глагола *хъдьти, откуда через *хьдьти > идти, причем, в основных формах "хь" перешло в "ь" (краткое гласное "е") *хьду > иду - *хьдемы > идем *хьдеши > идешь - *хьдете > идете *хьде > идет - *хьдут > идут в перфекте "хь" > "ш": *хь (дъ) л > шь (дъ) л > шел

Comment: Do you claim идти is unrelated to Latin iter and PIE e̯eiti "goes"?

Answer (score 2):

"X" mutating into "ш" - is not that rare, if it is not obvious with say "ход"/"шедший" this connection can be found for instance in such pairs like "тихий"/"тишь", "Михаил"/"Миша".

This started in Praslavic and it's part of well known and well studied process, it is actually called  "первая палатализация согласных" and it is about `к`, `г`, `х` mutating into soft `ч'`, `ж'`, `ш'` accordingly. The was also a second one (вторая палатализация), which is about the law of mutating the same set of consonants into `ц'`, `з'`, `c'`.

Up to the XIV century `ж'` and `ш'` (unlike `ч`) in Russian have lost their 
softness, but what you see in "шёл" is the remnant of palatalisation.

Regarding the fact that this happend in Proto-Slavic - and first palatalisation is present in all Slavic languages - the "what-if" part of you question is very hard to answer. It's sort of "what if we won't consider one of the main phonetic changes in Slavic languages"?

Well, I don't know. What if Pedersen's [law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruki_sound_law) never had happened?
To be honest, any answer will be pretty speculative.

Comment: I know about the palatalisations (if I do keep getting which one did which wrong). My question here is more about the reason for what I (perhaps wrongly) find to be an unexpected root vowel, and the hypothetical addition about the present-day regular past tense of `идти` doesn't require imagining that any of the systematic shifts from Proto-Slavic had never happened — just that this particular form had never been lost.

Comment: NikolayErshov - in that case I'm confused and it's not clear to me what you are asking? It was that way just because well, it was - and you are asking what if it had not been. I'm not arguing but I won't be surprised if I'm not the only one for whom this is not clear.

Comment: I'm asking for evidence to support or reject a hypothesis that the root yer in `*хьdlъ` shows an influence from the original, lost (but predictable) regular forms of the verb `*jьdti`. And, additionally, to reconstruct what those forms would have sounded like today.

Answer (score 1):

Если мы посмотрим на этот же глагол в сербском языке, то увидим.

Инфинитив "ићи" (ћ - сербская мягкая "ч", как в словах "ночь" - "ноћ", "печь" - "пећ"  и т.д.); в настоящем времени "ћ" чередуется с "д" - "ми идемо"; в прошедшем времени "ћ" чередуется с "ш" - "ми смо ишли".

То есть спряжение практически регулярно за исключением чередования "ћ-д-ш". Так что можно предположить, что и русское "шёл" / "шли" получилось чередованием "д"-"ш" и усечением начального "и" - "ишёл" / "ишла" / "ишло" / "ишли".

Comment: Похожее есть в словацком и украинском. Точечность этого явления и то, что "ш" как результат чередования "д" противоречит вообще всем славянским закономерностям, заставляет думать, что это более поздняя реэтимологизация, достаточно предсказуемая, чтобы произойти в нескольких языках независимо.

Answer (score 1):

Fasmer's dictionary gives шьлъ as an old form of шёл; this makes sense given х > ш (the first palatalization of velars) and the loss of д before л. The strong ь in шьлъ then becomes е, which (according to Vlasto) around the 12 century becomes o to result in шёл (for comparison he gives льнъ > лён, осьлъ > осёл).

Answer (score 0):

*шёл* is to *идти* as *вёл* to *вести*, not *водить*. *Водить / водил* and *ходить / ходил* seem quite regular to me.

I'm not aware of any reflexes other than *шёл* and *шествие* (*< шьствие*) which would have been used to reconstruct **xьd-*.

The contamination hypothesis would not let you get rid of **хod-*, and if you accept a root with another vowel gradation, **хed-* is not any better than **xьd-*. It does not explain any other reflexes, and you need to invoke an extra assumption about that contamination to justify the change in the root vowel.

Comment: My point was that *шёл* is to *ходить*, not *идти*, what *вёл* is to *водить*. And the root in the latter already has that change of vowel. I might be completely wrong about my basic assumptions if *вёл* is in fact from `*vьdlъ` and not `*vedlъ` (not being a professional, it's hard to always know what I don't know), but if that isn't the case, with *шёл* we have what seems to be an atypical vowel gradation when the one present in other motion verbs, whatever its explanation, is at least consistent.

Comment: change in the root vowel is due to ш was soft initially

Comment: @NikolayErshov: *вёл* is of course from _*vedlъ_. But vowel gradation is a grammatic phenomenon, not phonetic, which had stopped being productive long before the advent of Proto-Slavic. You can find both _ь/о_ pairs (_*mьrti/moriti_) and _е/о_ pairs (already mentioned _*vedti/voditi_) and pretty much all other combinations you can think about.

Comment: @shabunc: change from what to what?

Comment: @Quassnoi None of them with motion verbs, though, am I right? `*Neslъ`, `*vezlъ`, etc. No `ь` root that I can think of, except this one.

Comment: @NikolayErshov: why do you think verb semantics would have something to do with the way it forms iteratives or causatives through the ablaut? Not sure if it's motion enough, but *stьg- / stog-* (*> достигать / стогна*) seems like an example.

Comment: @Quassnoi No reason, just an observed tendency and an exception from it. That said, motion verbs aren't an entirely semantic category; the reason *достигать* doesn't qualify is that it doesn't have a directional and non-directional variation. But I do realise that `*xod-` didn't *have* to become `*xed-`. rather than `*xьd-`, like most other directional motion verb roots, and that it may have already settled into `*xьd-` for reasons that predate these categories as such. I suppose this means that there's no conclusive answer and my proposed contamination with `*jьd-` doesn't pass Occam's razor.

Comment: @NikolayErshov: *достогнать* is attested in Russian, and its cognates are quite widely attested in many IE languages with meanings "to walk by feet, to climb": "stile", "stair", *στίχος* ("a file, rank, as of people marching"). It just happened so that zero-grade and o-grade did make it all the way into the modern Russian, and e-grade did not (but did in other languages).

Answer (score -1):

There are also another similar words "шастать" (old Russian word) or "шляться" (more like slang) , which I would translate as "walking" or "walking around". 
But "шастать" has its own past form "шастал". Maybe they had some impact on the origin of "шёл"