# The lexical root of the past tense forms differrent from the lexical root of the infinitive form

Tags: этимология, супплетивизм

Does Russian have any verbs, whose past tense forms are based on the lexical root that differs from the lexical root of the infinitive form (by analogy with the Latin verb fero > tuli)?

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12627/the-exact-origin-of-%d1%88%d1%91%d0%bb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Russian, cases of suppletive paradigms are in general very few and far between but [a little more frequent in nouns](http://archive.is/v3xKd) than in verbs, among which **идти - шёл** is probably the only semblance thereof because it can't be branded as a classic case due to etymological reasons.

Another, tangentially related case is a case of aspectual pairs **брать - взять**, **говорить - сказать**, **ловить - поймать** where verbs of different aspects, contrary to the expectations and the norm, derive from different roots.